# Unity (new) InputSystem does respond to mouse clicks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, input

I am building this simple game, where a bunch of fellows that I have are supposed to seek a point indicated by a mouse click. The issue is that the Editor does not seem to notice mouse clicks at runtime. I have used the exact Input Action Asset before for detecting presses of "g" button, but it seemed to have stopped working when I played with it some more sometime later. I have since removed the asset and created w new Action Assets (one that I created manually and another that I created through the Input Action component button). Neither of them works. I have no idea what is going on and I have been looking at this for several hours now. Can someone please explain what I might have done wrong?

[image: SceneManager picture - where my Input Actions component and SceneManager script is attached to]

[image: Input Actions Asset layout; the one created through the component rather than manually]

Different functions I used to try and get the Editor to respond to my code are below. MouseClick() is the original function that I needed to run, but did not work, onFire() is my attempt at running the default one that is given if Actions Asset is isnantiated through the component.
[image]

Comment: The exception seems to have little to do with the input actions but rather a collection being modified while you are iterating it (e.g. adding/removing items within a `foreach` loop). Please share enough code for us to reproduce the issue and [**DON'T upload images of code!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the issue was that the functions are supposed to be capitalized at the start.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the performed event ?
Also your Fire action needs to be a button type

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused - what do you mean by "performed event" and the last bit - the Fire action is a button type (as set in the Editor in the Input Action Asset), unless you mean something else by that.

Comment: yeah i was talking about that :)
The performed event is introduced the input system package you actually use.
It is an alternative to Input messages
More infos about it here for example : https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Actions.html